# echoing data from json

Tags: php, json

http://pastebin.com/FE2i1sqV - this is the json data file...

This is the code I use to print my city which is in json file on linenum:20

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("path/to/json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
echo "${location}\n";
```

Now I'm having problems on how to print out content from the "forecast" array which is located on linenum 154 of the JSON file. Basically I need an outpout from content where period is 0, 1 and 2.
I just need a working example of one row - I can figure out the rest on my own - How else am I to learn if everyone solves everything for me :)

Thnx in advance :P

Comment: That’s not valid JSON; in JSON, the `/` needs to be escaped as `\/`.

Comment: If your are referring to path - that's put their for this example - I don't want my API key to be revealed :)

Comment: @Gumbo: It does not have to, it can be.

Comment: @Gumbo: Mmh. Then http://jsonlint.com/ has to be updated. But according to the [spec](http://json.org/), it does not have to. It says a strings can consist of *"Every unicode character except `"` or ``\`` or control character"* and lists a couple of characters which are allowed to follow ``\``.

Comment: @FelixKling According to [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627) it must be escaped: `unescaped = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF` and `\‍` is U+005D.

Comment: @Gumbo: I'm confused now... `/` is `%x2F` which is in the range of `%x23-5B`... so it should be fine? Or am I not understanding this at all?

Comment: Um, er, never mind. Must be the lack of coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$array = $parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday;
$new_array = array_filter($array, function($elem){return $elem->period < 3;});
print_r($new_array);
echo "First fcttext: " . $new_array[0]->fcttext;
```

Comment: Thank you, that would be it. I'll need to sort out the elements and format them properly.